# Python packaging: How to prevent user from installing my package with wrong python version

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-wheel

**Environment:**

- pip version: 21.2.4
- twine version: 3.4.1
- Python version: 3.9.7

I have made a python package developed in the above environment and distributing with pypi (`pip install`). The problem is that while the package requires python 3.8 or newer due to `typing.Literal` for type hinting, the package somehow can be installed with python 3.7. As a result, user gets an error when importing but not on installation.
I want to fix this behavior but setting `python_requires=">=3.8.0"` in `setup.py` does not change anything.

How can I let user know that they don't have compatible python version when installing?

I have observed that happened by installing my package on Google COLAB which has python3.7 and pip version 21.1.3.